# Aerospike Config for a Small Server

Tags: aerospike

I'd like to know what the ideal Aerospike namespace configuration is for a mini (staging) server on Ubuntu 12.04 with 1 GB ram and 1 GHz CPU

Some requirements:
1. I'd like to persist data permanently on disk (not using it as a cache).
2. I'm only using a single node
3. I don't want a limit on the filesize of my data

Here's my current config snippet I'm using:

```
namespace default {
        replication-factor 1
        memory-size 1G
        default-ttl 0 # not sure if this is for cache or disk

        storage-engine device {
                file /opt/aerospike/data/default.dat
                filesize 2T
                data-in-memory true
        }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Aerospike doesn't cache [data-in-memory](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/reference/configuration/#data-in-memory). If `data-in-memory` is set to *true* then all of your data must fit in RAM.
2. On a single node you will not be affected by the `replication-factor` parameter.
3. Aerospike has a [limit of 2 TiB per file](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/reference/configuration/#filesize), but you can create multiple files of this size and Aerospike will distribute data across them. When going through a filesystem, having multiple files often helps. Also if you are going to use a filesystem then you may wan to look into disabling atime when mounting the disks.
4. [default-ttl](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/reference/configuration/#default-ttl) is how long the server will keep a record after it is written by default (can be overridden by your application). A default-ttl of 0 mean to never [expire](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/operations/manage/storage/#expiring-data-that-has-reached-ttl) or [evict](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/operations/manage/storage/#eviction) data.

Example config with multiple files:

```
namespace default {
        replication-factor 1
        memory-size 1G
        default-ttl 0 # (This applies to the primary index)

        storage-engine device {
                file /opt/aerospike/data/file0.dat
                file /opt/aerospike/data/file1.dat
                file /opt/aerospike/data/file2.dat
                file /opt/aerospike/data/file3.dat
                file /opt/aerospike/data/file4.dat
                file /opt/aerospike/data/file5.dat
                filesize 2T
                data-in-memory true
        }
}
```

Comment: Ok thank you @kporter, 1.  so to be 100% clear re #4, if I'm persisting data to disk, if my default-ttl is 30D then I'm going to *lose* that data on disk as well after that period?  If yes, therefore to use aerospike as a "normal" data store I'd have to set this to 0?   Also 2.  Is there any way to not set a limit on the data files (i.e using this as a "normal" database)?  Kind of annoying that one has to set this "file" setting

Comment: The data on disk will not be referenced after 30d and may be overwritten if that is the ttl. There isn't a way to have unlimited disk space, the max size per file is 2TiB. You can later add more files at the end of your configuration and Aerospike will redistribute the data at runtime as client and server triggered writes come in.

Comment: Also, the index for the data on disk is stored in RAM. Each index entry will occupy 64 bytes of RAM.